# How can a view determine its height based on a function of its width without using an intrinsicContentSize that is dependent on the frame?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to figure out how best to create a view that determines its own height based on the width it is given. The behaviour I desire is very similar to how a vertical UIStackView behaves in that:

- When constrained by its **top**, **leading**, and **trailing** edges, it should determine its own natural height based on its content.
- When constrained on **all edges**, it should fill all the available space by expanding and collapsing as determined by those constraints.
- In addition, I am looking to achieve this without using autolayout internally to my view.

To illustrate this, please consider the following example:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let v = View()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

            // Toggle this constraint on and off.
            // v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),
        ])
    }
}

class View: UIView {

    // Imagine this came from computing the size of some child views
    // and that it is relative to the width of the bounds.
    var contentHeight: CGFloat { bounds.width * 0.5 }

    var boundsWidth: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet { if oldValue != boundsWidth { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() } }
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        .init(width: bounds.width, height: contentHeight)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        boundsWidth = bounds.width
        backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

This example achieves the behaviour I've described above but I have a big reservation with it because of how I'm using `intrinsicContentSize`.

The [documentation for `instrinsicContentSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622600-intrinsiccontentsize) states that it **must be independent of the content frame**, which I have not managed. I am calculating the intrinsic size based on the width of the frame.

How is it possible to achieve this behaviour **and** not make `instrinsicContentSize` rely on the bounds?

Comment: You provided more detail, but it's still not clear exactly what you're trying to do. *"create a view that determines its own height based on the width it is given"* --- do you want the height to be a **percentage** of the width? Are you planning on adding subviews to this view, and you want the height(s) of the subviews to determine the height of the view?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I was -perhaps wrongly- skipping those points because I thought they detracted from my actual question!

The particular view I'm working on will be a container for many smaller subviews that I will position internally. To simplify things you could picture a vertical UIStackView. I used a percentage of the width in the example code in the hope that people would gloss over it and focus on the more general question: 

How can a view determine its height based on *some computation* of it's width without using an intrinsicContentSize that is dependent on the frame.

Answer (score 1):

This can all be done with auto-layout constraints. No need to calculate anything.

All you need to do is make sure your custom view's content has appropriate constraints to define the layout.

For example, a `UILabel` has an intrinsic size based on its text. You can constrain a "top" label to the top of the view, a "middle" label to the bottom of the "top" label, and a "bottom" label to the bottom of the "middle" label **and** to the bottom of the view.

Here's an example (all via code):

```
class SizeTestViewController: UIViewController {

    let v = ExampleView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(v)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),

        ])

        v.topLabel.text = "This is the top label."
        v.middleLabel.text = "This is a bunch of text for the middle label. Since we have it set to numberOfLines = 0, the text will wrap onto mutliple lines (assuming it needs to)."
        v.bottomLabel.text = "This is the bottom label text\nwith embedded newline characters\nso we can see the multiline feature without needing word wrap."

        // so we can see the view's frame
        v.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}

class ExampleView: UIView {
    var topLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .yellow
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    var middleLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    var bottomLabel: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .green
        v.numberOfLines = 0
        return v
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {

        addSubview(topLabel)
        addSubview(middleLabel)
        addSubview(bottomLabel)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            // constrain topLabel 8-pts from top, leading, trailing
            topLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            topLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            topLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // constrain middleLabel 8-pts from topLabel
            //  8-pts from leading, trailing
            middleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            middleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            middleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),

            // constrain bottomLabel 8-pts from middleLabel
            //  8-pts from leading, trailing
            //  8-pts from bottom
            bottomLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: middleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            bottomLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            bottomLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            bottomLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8.0),

        ])

    }

}
```

The result:

[image]

and rotated, so you can see the auto-sizing:

[image]

---

**Edit**

A little clarification on **Intrinsic Content Size**...

In this image, all 5 subviews have an `intrinsicContentSize` of `120 x 80`:

```
class IntrinsicTestView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 120, height: 80)
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see:

- If I ***don't*** add constraints to specify **Width** - either with a Width constraint or Leading and Trailing constraints - the view will be 120-pts wide.
- If I ***don't*** add constraints to specify **Height** - either with a Height constraint or Top and Bottom constraints - the view will be 80-pts tall.
- Otherwise, the width and height will be determined by the constraints I've added.

Here's the complete code for that example:

```
class IntrinsicTestView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 120, height: 80)
    }
}

class IntrinsicExampleViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var iViews: [IntrinsicTestView] = [IntrinsicTestView]()

        var v: IntrinsicTestView

        let colors: [UIColor] = [.red, .green, .blue, .yellow, .purple]

        colors.forEach { c in
            let v = IntrinsicTestView()
            v.backgroundColor = c
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
            iViews.append(v)
        }

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // first view at Top: 20 / Leading: 20
        v = iViews[0]
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        // second view at Top: 120 / Leading: 20
        //  height: 20
        v = iViews[1]
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 120.0).isActive = true
        v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

        // third view at Top: 160 / Leading: 20
        //  height: 40 / width: 250
        v = iViews[2]
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 160.0).isActive = true
        v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true

        // fourth view at Top: 220
        //  trailing: 20 / width: 250
        v = iViews[3]
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 220.0).isActive = true
        v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
        v.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 250).isActive = true

        // fourth view at Top: 400 / Leading: 20
        //  trailing: 20 / bottom: 20
        v = iViews[4]
        v.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 400.0).isActive = true
        v.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true
        v.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true
        v.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0).isActive = true

    }

}
```

Comment: That’s awesome, thanks for your answer! 
Do you know of a way to solve the same problem without constraints?

Comment: @user1636130 - well, that's pretty much the very definition of "auto-layout." You use constraints to tell the auto-layout engine how you want your views and subviews to be arranged on the screen. And, normally, you do so in a way that your get your desired layout on different screen sizes / orientations. Not even sure how else you would envision this working? You want to have a view size itself, based on its content (subviews), but you don't want to use constraints to tell that view ***how*** to size itself?

Comment: In my particular situation, the positioning of the subviews is sufficiently complicated such that its worth my time to explore a frame based approach rather than using auto-layout. It will yield much simpler and testable logic in this particular scenario. If I could get a good understanding of how to use `intrinsicContentSize` then I'd be in a good place :)

Comment: @user1636130 - as a general rule, the more "complicated" the layout, the more beneficial constraints become. But... if you feel that is not the case... when you `override var intrinsicContentSize`, you are simply telling auto-layout "use this size unless something tells you differently." Perhaps if you post a **real** example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @user1636130 - see the **Edit** to my answer. I added some clarification on **Intrinsic Content Size**

Answer (score 0):

As DonMag said in his response, `intrinsicContentSize` is not quite intended for complex layout management but rather as an indication of a View's preferred size when there are not enough constraints for his frame.

However, there is a simple example i can provide to hopefully point you in the right direction.
Let's assume i want a `RatioView` to be intrinsically sized so that its height is a linear function of its width:

```
let ratioView = RatioView()
ratioView.ratio = 0.5
```

in this example, `ratioView` will have an intrinsic height equal to half of his width.

The code for `RatioView` is the following:

```
class RatioView: UIView {
  var contentHeight: CGFloat { bounds.width * ratio }
  private var kvoObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?

  var ratio: CGFloat = 1 {
    didSet { invalidateIntrinsicContentSize() }
  }

  override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    .init(width: bounds.width, height: contentHeight)
  }

  override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    guard let _ = superview else { return }
    kvoObservation = observe(\.frame, options: .initial) { [weak self] (_, change) in
      self?.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
  }

  override func willMove(toSuperview newSuperview: UIView?) {
    if newSuperview == nil {
      kvoObservation = nil
    }
  }
}
```

There are two important highligths in the above code:

- the view calls [`invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622457-invalidateintrinsiccontentsize) to inform the layout system that the value of his `intrinsicContentSize` property has changed.
- the view is constantly monitoring via [KVO observation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/using_key-value_observing_in_swift) any changes to his `frame` property, so that it can calculate its new height every time its width changes.

The second step is especially noteworthy: without it, the view wouldn't know *when* its size is changing and thus wouldn't have any chance to inform the layout system (via `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`) that its `intrinsicContentSize` has been refreshed.